# How can I select sibling nodes in XML using XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Assuming the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <info>
        <code>
            ABC
        </code>
        <desc>
            A
        </desc>
    </info>
    <info>
        <code>
            DEF
        </code>
        <desc>
            A
        </desc>
    </info>
    <info>
        <code>
            XYZ
        </code>
        <desc>
            B
        </desc>
    </info>
</root>
```

How can I select all of the `code` elements that have a `desc` value of 'A'?

I tried the following XPath, and it gave me nothing:

```
/root/info[desc='A']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @Jim Garrison said, you'll need to use `normalize-space()` on `<desc>` but you can pretty much keep the xpath that you had with the addition of `/code` (and `normalize-space()`)

```
/root/info[normalize-space(desc)='A']/code
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/root/info/code[normalize-space(../desc/text())='A']
```

I.e. tell it which nodes you want (`/root/info/code`), filtered by the condition.  You need the `normalize-space()` because there's whitespace on both sides of the values in the source document.